# what are the detailed steps to setup test asp.net site using free SSL certificate in IIS6?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, ssl

Please provide detailed steps to setup IIS6 could not found good information by googling...
Is there free SSL certificates that can be used only to test locally?

Comment: Do you have a Windows domain, i.e. do you have a domain certificate authority you can use? I can talk you through that. Otherwise it looks like you want to get SelfSSL from the [IIS 6 resource kit] - have you tried that?

Comment: No I don't have Windows domain certificate authority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the [IIS 6 resource kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499). Install at least the SelfSSL utility.
2. Open a command prompt; go to `C:\Program Files\IIS Resources\SelfSSL` and

   ```
   selfssl /T /N:CN=localhost /V:365
   ```

   This will generate a self-signed certificate for https://localhost/ and offer to install it for you in each web site on your system. This will also add it to your trusted certificate store so that IE will automatically accept the certificate. The `/V` option is the number of days the certificate will be valid for, i.e. roughly a year.

   If you want to use https://your-machine-name/ instead of localhost then just change or omit the `/N:` option. If not the first you can specify which specific site using `/S:`. And there are other options avialable to configure the key generation if you need them.

Normally when you install an SSL certificate in IIS you'd also need to `iisreset` before it'll work but SelfSSL takes care of this too.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using [IISExpress](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) to test SSL which is super easy....
steps to setup : * just run web platform installer * configure to run in iis6 compatibily mode but its not true IIS 6 :)